# Replacing multiple values in a column from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a table with values like these:

```
COLUMN_STRING
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Author = ""DAVID"" or Author = ""PETER"" and Date > ""01/01/2018""
Owner = ""JOSEPH"" and Author <> ""KATHLEEN"" and Category = ""Drama""
Creator = ""RAPHAEL"" and Reviewer = ""PAMELA"" and Owner = ""MICHAEL""
```

And I have another table with the replacement matchings:

```
OLD_VALUE      NEW_VALUE
-------------------------
DAVID          DAVE
PETER          PETE
JOSEPH         JOE
KATHLEEN       KATE
RAPHAEL        RAPH
PAMELA         PAM
MICHAEL        MIKE
```

Would it be possible to have a SQL `UPDATE` statement or function where I can replace the `OLD_VALUE` with the `NEW_ONE` in the first table?

So resulting values should be:

```
COLUMN_STRING
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Author = ""DAVE"" or Author = ""PETE"" and Date > ""01/01/2018""
Owner = ""JOE"" and Author <> ""KATE"" and Category = ""Drama""
Creator = ""RAPH"" and Reviewer = ""PAM"" and Owner = ""MIKE""
```

Thanks

Comment: This can be quite complicated.  What would happen if you had "PAMELAIKER" in the data?

Comment: The `column_string` column looks very suspiciously like a collection of `WHERE` conditions. And it just itches my nose that you could very well be going down a very complicated path to achieve something that might be much easier using SQL capabilities - 

Could you share with us what it is in general that you want to achieve - and we could maybe give you a more to-the-point answer?

Comment: Hi Gordon, If "PAMELAIKER" is in the data then not replacement should happen, I think it's important to consider the quotes.

Comment: Hi Marco, column_string has more complex strings but they are not SQL language, but you are right, it's like a search spec. Users logins are being updated to something else so we need to make sure that these references to old user logins are being updated as well.